# Content Security Policy: style-src 'self' alternative for inline-styles?

Tags: html, css, security, content-security-policy

Hello we try to build a web service with security being an important issue. We apply the content security policy in the header like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'
```

The problem is that for reasons of the functionality of certain Javascript/JQuery libraries the inline styles are just needed (we cannot rewrite all the libraries) ans that there will also be user content written in TinyMCE or some other HTML Editor, so dissallowing CSS inline-styles is not an option.

Here is an answer why this can be a security issue:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2012Mar/0046.html

Does anybody know a possiblity to "whitelist" certain inline styles (e.g. allow color and font-size, but dissallow background images and advanced CSS features)? Is a Server-Side secure Whitelist filter in PHP possible (recommendation welcome!)?

Comment: would using a nonce or hash be good enough? that would allow you to whitelist certain stylesheets provided by the server.

Comment: yeah that MAY be a solution :-) Currently: We solve it this way and also install HTML Purifier with whitelist HTML/CSS properties for every possibly displayed HTML. But maybe somebody still knows an alternative